# There is no possibility to move photos within content editing [TinyMCE 6]

Tags: tinymce, wysiwyg

There is a problem in firefox. You cannot move the photo to another position. There is no such problem in chrome.

Does anyone know why it works like this?

Browser: Firefox and Chrome (last update)

https://youtu.be/zYNVTK6PPZw

Comment: It works in my version of Firefox. E.g., in this fiddle: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/cziaab
Please share your TinyMCE config. You can also try to test this case in Incognito mode — some Firefox plugins might interfere with TinyMCE. The Incognito mode will disable them.

Comment: Ahh. You're right. Everything works fine without plugins. Thank you :D